# Is dropout (deep learning) even consistent?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, dropout

I'm learning about dropout from these sources:

- https://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/#reg
- https://arxiv.org/abs/1207.0580

At test time, the trained weights are scaled by a factor of $p$, to replace them with their mean. According to the original paper this is kind of like an approximation to an ensemble of the $2^n$ possible dropout models that "works well in practice".

It's an approximation because the network isn't a linear function of its weights.

Is there any justification for this approximation?

It's not even clear to me that dropout is a consistent estimator.

Answer (score 5):

From Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville's book, Deep Learning:

> A key insight (Hinton et al., 2012c) involved in dropout is that we
>   can approximate $p_\mathrm{ensemble}$ by evaluating $p(y|\mathbf{x})$
>   in one model: the model with all units, but with the weights going out
>   of unit $i$ multiplied by the probability of including unit $i$. The
>   motivation for this modification is to capture the right expected
>   value of the output from that unit. We call this approach the weight
>   scaling inference rule. **There is not yet any theoretical argument for
>   the accuracy of this approximate inference rule in deep nonlinear
>   networks, but empirically it performs very well.**

(Emphasis mine)